# ¿Cómo montar un disco duro NTFS en Linux (Debian)?

Tags: linux, debian, ntfs

Tengo un disco duro (externo) con formato NTFS, y necesito copiar archivos de este disco a mi computadora, que funciona con Debian Linux. Generalmente, basta con conectar cualquier unidad USB y Debian la reconoce automáticamente; sin embargo, parece no reconocer automáticamente este disco NTFS.

¿Cómo puedo montar este disco en Linux?.

Comment: Encuentro la pregunta útil pero creo que no está vinculada a programación de alguna manera.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza en Stack Overflow en español estamos considerando por el momento preguntas que tienen que ver con otros temas realcionados, en particular esta pregunta sería on topic en serverfault  por lo que por el momento si es relevante en es.SO http://meta.es.stackoverflow.com/a/166/20

Comment: @CarlosMuñoz gracias, no lo sabía. De igual manera, solo puse el comentario, no el voto en contra.

Comment: Aquí un artículo que te puede ser de utilidad [Montar NTFS en Debian Linux](http://www.taringa.net/posts/linux/1659083/Montar-NTFS-en-Debian-Linux.html)

Comment: @CarlosMuñoz: Pero este clase de pregunta tiene [-11 puntos](http://meta.es.stackoverflow.com/a/162/22). Está fuera de la temática.

Comment: @Flimzy no confundas superuser con serverfault

Comment: @CarlosMuñoz: No lo hice. Aunque es verdad que un administrador puede tener esa pregunta, es más una pregunta para SuperUser. Y aunque puede ser dentro de la temática para ServerFault, es mi opinión que este clase de pregunta obviamente no pertenece aquí.

Comment: Esta pregunta no es de programación, debería ser cerrada. Veo que en el sitio hay demasiada pregunta off-topic.

Comment: @jpangamarca entiendo tu comentario, y si deseas votar para cerrar la pregunta, eres libre de hacerlo. Sin embargo, te sugiero veas el comentario de Carlos Muñoz y la liga que provee

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Encontré la solución [aquí](https://beginlinux.wordpress.com/2009/03/18/mounting-an-ntfs-drive-in-debian/); si alguien tiene este problema, pongo aquí los pasos más relevantes:

En primer lugar, hay que instalar dos paquetes para poder leer unidades NTFS: `libfuse2` y `ntfs-3g`. Para instalar estos paquetes, hay que escribir los siguientes comandos en la consola (es necesario utilizar la cuenta de usuario `root`):

```bash
apt-get install libfuse2
apt-get install ntfs-3g
```

Una vez instalados estos paquetes, es posible montar el volumen NTFS de que se trate. En una consola (con el usuario `root`) hay que verificar dónde está conectado el disco. El siguiente comando muestra las particiones NTFS conectadas:

```bash
fdisk -l | grep -i ntfs
```

(La opción `-i` es para ignorar mayúsculas y minúsculas al momento de filtrar los resultados de `fdisk -l`).

El resultado, en mi caso, es este:

```bash
/dev/sdb1              63  1953520064   976760001    7  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
```

Así que, en mi caso, el disco NTFS externo está conectado en `/dev/sdb1`. Ahora, hay que crear un punto de montaje. Para ello, hay que crear una carpeta para este propósito. En mi caso, cree una carpeta llamada `windows` en `/media`:

```bash
mkdir /media/windows
```

Y ahora, por fin, para montar el disco:

```bash
mount -t ntfs-3g /dev/sdb1 /media/windows
```

El disco está ahora disponible para leer su contenido.

**Importante:** Al terminar de usar el disco, hay que desmontarlo antes de desconectarlo:

```bash
umount /dev/sdb1
```

Espero que esta información sea útil.