# Raspberry PI 3 - ejecutar Firefox cuando inicie el ambiente gráfico?

Tags: linux, debian

Tengo un Raspberry PI 3 con Raspbian Desktop (debian) y quiero que cuando inicie el ambiente gráfico se ejecute automáticamente Firefox.

Comment: Voto por cerrar esta pregunta como tema no relacionado porque esto nada tiene que ver con programación, es configuración de sistemas

Comment: entonces porque existe la etiqueta *debian* ?, sera porque es amante de Microsoft ?

Comment: porque hay preguntas que sí tienen que ver con programación relacionadas a debian

Comment: y porque le molesta o en que le afecta la publicación ?

Comment: no me molesta, es efecto de moderación del sitio. Por cierto, luego que editaste tu comentario y agregaste: `sera porque es amante de Microsoft ? ` Nada tiene que ver.

Comment: ok.............

Comment: @fredyfx deberias leer el 2do commentario de aqui --> https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/1460/c%C3%B3mo-montar-un-disco-duro-ntfs-en-linux-debian?rq=1

Comment: Entonces, creo que deberías publicar la pregunta en: https://serverfault.com/ :D

Comment: Los criterios en SOes han ido cambiando con el tiempo, comparto la opinión de @fredyfx, la última discusión en meta al respecto: https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/3336/son-v%C3%A1lidas-las-preguntas-sobre-instalaci%C3%B3n-de-sistemas-operativos. De todas formas, esto: https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/51812, tal vez pueda ayudarte.

Comment: @moneyBox si deseas conversar, me ubicas por twitter :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Encontré la respuesta :D

Hay que editar el archivo:

```
/etc/xdg/lxsession/LXDE-__tu_username__/autostart
```

Y agregar la linea de comando iniciando por **@**, ejemplos:

```
shell# nano autostart

@/home/miusuario/miscript.sh
@/usr/bin/firefox
```

Lo interesante de **autostart** a diferencia de Cron, es que esos comandos que ingresas se ejecutarán **después** de haber iniciado sesión el usuario, así que, por cada usuario que exista en el sistema verás una carpeta específica en `/etc/xdg/lxsession/`.

Otro punto importante es que el script se ejecuta a nivel de cuenta de usuario, y no como root. A menos que escribas los comandos en el "autostart" del root, pero solo se efectuarán dentro de la sesión gráfica (xwindow) del usuario.